# Issue with Image Display in React Carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Description:
I'm building a React application with an image carousel using the provided `Carousel` component. However, I'm facing an issue with the second slide's image not displaying correctly. The first slide displays perfectly, but when the carousel moves to the second slide, the image is not shown properly.

Here is the code for the relevant components and styles:

`index.tsx`:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root') as Element;
if (rootElement) {
  const root = createRoot(rootElement);
  root.render(<App />);
}
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './sass/main.scss';
import Home from './adminheader/home';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const  About:  React.FC = () => {
  return <h1>About Page</h1>;
}

const NotFound:  React.FC = () => {
  return <h1>Page Not Found</h1>;
}

const App: React.FC = () =>{
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> Default view
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Home.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "../sass/main.scss";
import Carousel from './carousel';
interface Slide { id:number ,title: string;  url: string;  content: string;}
const Home: React.FC = () => {  
  const [list, setList] = useState<Slide[]>([{
    id:1,
    title: "First slide",
    url: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71HQVbIfrxL.MCnd_AC_UL320.jpg",
    content: "Some text for the first slide"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    title: "Second slide",
    url: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71kI8lXGhXL.MCnd_AC_UL320.jpg",
    content: "Some text for the second slide"
  },
  {
    id:3,
    title: "Third slide",
    url: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71eOh+U4baL.AC_UL320.jpg",
    content: "Some text for the third slide"
  },]);

  return (   
<div className="grid-container">
  <div className="grid-row">
  <div className="grid-column-12 grid-column-sm-6 grid-column-md-4">   </div>       
   </div>
   <div className="grid-row">
  <div className="grid-column-4 grid-column-sm-4 grid-column-md-4">  </div>
   <div className="grid-column-8 grid-column-sm-8 grid-column-md-8"> <Carousel slides={list} /> </div>       
   </div>
  <div className="grid-row">
  <div className="grid-column-12 grid-column-sm-6 grid-column-md-8">  </div>       
   </div>
 </div>  
  );
}

export default Home;
```

`Carousel.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
interface Slide { id:number, title: string;  url: string;  content: string;}
interface CarouselProps {  slides: Slide[];}
const Carousel: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({ slides }) => {  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState<number>(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = 
    setInterval(() => {    
        goToNextSlide(); 
         }, 3000); // change this value as needed
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [currentSlide]); 

  const goToNextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentSlide((prevSlide) => (prevSlide === slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevSlide + 1));
  };  

  const goToPrevSlide = () => {
    setCurrentSlide((prevSlide) => (prevSlide === 0 ? slides.length - 1 : prevSlide - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <div className="carousel-slides">
        {slides.map((slide, index) => (
          <div
            className={`carousel-item ${index === currentSlide ? 'active' : ''}`}   key={`carouselitemdiv${index}`}  >
            <img id={`carouselitemimage${slide.id}`} src={slide.url} alt={slide.title} /> 
            <div className="carousel-content">  <h3>{slide.title}</h3>  <p>{slide.content}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-indicators">
        {slides.map((_, index) => (
          <input key={`slidekey${index + 1}`}  type="radio" name="carousel" id={`slide${index + 1}`} className="carousel-radio"  checked={index === currentSlide}
             onChange={() => setCurrentSlide(index)}
          />
        ))}
        {slides.map((_, index) => (
          <label  htmlFor={`slide${index + 1}`}  key={`slidelabelkey${index + 1}`}></label>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-navigation">
        <button className="prev" onClick={goToPrevSlide}>&lt;</button>
        <button className="next" onClick={goToNextSlide}>&gt;</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Carousel;
```

`main.scss`:

```scss
@use 'base/reset';
@use 'base/typography';
@use 'components/grid';
@use 'components/carousel';
```

`_reset.scss`:

```scss
// A simple reset of styles for all elements
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

// Remove the default styling of some elements
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
// Use variables for colors
$primary-color: #007bff;
$secondary-color: #6c757d;
$success-color: #28a745;
$danger-color: #dc3545;
$info-color: #17a2b8;
$warning-color: #ffc107;

// Use mixins for buttons
@mixin button-style($color) {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: $color;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.9);
  }
}
```

`_typography.scss`:

```scss
// _typography.scss
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap');
// Font Families
$default-font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
// Font Sizes
$base-font-size: 16px;
$heading-1-size: 32px;
$heading-2-size: 24px;
$heading-3-size: 20px;
$heading-4-size: 18px;

// Font Weights
$regular-font-weight: 400;
$bold-font-weight: 700;
// Line Height
$base-line-height: 1.5;
// Text Colors
$default-text-color: #000000;
$link-color: #146eb4;

// Text Alignment
$text-alignment: left;

// Typography Styles
body {
  font-family: $default-font-family;
  font-size: $base-font-size;
  line-height: $base-line-height;
  color: $default-text-color;
  text-align: $text-alignment;
}

h1, .h1 {
  font-size: $heading-1-size;
  font-weight: $bold-font-weight;
}

h2, .h2 {
  font-size: $heading-2-size;
  font-weight: $bold-font-weight;
}

h3, .h3 {
  font-size: $heading-3-size;
  font-weight: $bold-font-weight;
}

h4, .h4 {
  font-size: $heading-4-size;
  font-weight: $bold-font-weight;
}

a {
  color: $link-color;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

`_grid.scss`:

```scss
@use "sass:math";

$columns: 12;
$gap: 20px;
$breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
);
$container-width: (
  xs: 100%,
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 100%
);

@mixin media($breakpoint) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
    $value: map-get($breakpoints, $breakpoint);
    @media (min-width: $value) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @warn "Invalid breakpoint: #{$breakpoint}.";
  }
}

@mixin grid-container() {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: $gap;
    max-width: map-get($container-width, xs);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    @each $breakpoint, $value in $breakpoints {
      @include media($breakpoint) {
        max-width: map-get($container-width, $breakpoint);
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin grid-row() {
  .grid-row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($columns, minmax(0,1fr)); // use minmax to prevent overflow
    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
      @include media($breakpoint) {
        @if $breakpoint == sm {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(math.div($columns,2), minmax(0,1fr));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin grid-column() {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .grid-column-#{$i} {
      grid-column-start: span $i; // use start and end properties to allow multiple classes
      grid-column-end: auto;
    }
    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
      @include media($breakpoint) {
        .grid-column-#{$breakpoint}-#{$i} {
          grid-column-start: span $i;
          grid-column-end: auto;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include grid-container();
@include grid-row();
@include grid-column();
```

`_carousel.scss`:

```scss
.carousel {
  width: 70vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 400px;

  .carousel-slides {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    max-height: 50vh; // adjust this value as needed 

    &.active {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  
    &.next {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
  
    &.prev {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    &:not(.active) {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    .carousel-content {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      text-align: center;

      h3 {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .carousel-indicators {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 15px;

    label {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
      margin: 0 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;

      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      }
    }

    input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }

  .carousel-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;

    .prev,
    .next {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;

      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
      }

      &:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      &:active {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using these packages

```
"@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
"@types/node": "^16.18.24",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-icons": "^4.9.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"sass": "^1.63.3",
"typescript": "^4.9.5",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

Issue Details:
The problem seems to be related to the `max-height` property set on the `.carousel-item` class in the `_carousel.scss` file. I tried adjusting the value of `max-height`, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I expect the second slide's image to be displayed correctly, just like the first slide. The carousel should smoothly transition between slides, showing each image along with its title and content.

Any help in identifying and resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!